# Delete multiple rows from Association Table in SQLAlchemy using db.session.execute syntax?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an association table that contains relationships between two other SQLAlchemy models that I would like to delete:

```
class ItemCategories(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("item.id"))
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("category.id"))
    # ... other fields
```

The old syntax was to use something like:

```
db.session.query(ItemCategories).filter_by(category_id=5).filter(ItemCategories.name="Shelved").delete()
```

But with the newer syntax, I tried:

```
db.session.execute(db.select(ItemCategories).filter_by(category_id=5).filter(ItemCategories.name="Shelved").delete())
```

But this errored with:

> AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'delete'

[Flask-SQLAlchemy suggests doing](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#deleting-records):

```
db.session.delete(Model Object)
```

But this only deletes a single row, and I would like to delete multiple rows at once. I know I can loop through all the rows and do a session delete one-by-one, but would prefer a bulk delete instead like with the `session.query` line.

Is there a way to do multiple deletes with `db.session.execute()`?

Comment: Perhaps try `db.delete(ItemCategories).filter_by(category_id=5).filter(ItemCategories.name="Shelved")`

Comment: Is that sqlalchemy syntax? How come it doesn't require `db.session` part?

Comment: That would be what goes inside the `db.session.execute()`. (But I don't use flask-sqlalchemy, so I can't say for sure.) So `db.session.execute(db.delete(ItemCategories).filter_by(category_id=5).filter(ItemCategories.name="Shelved"))`

Comment: I checked and it does seem that `db.delete == delete` where delete is from `from sqlalchemy.sql import delete`.  So @GordThompson last comment does should work fine.  I couldn't find it in the Flask SQLAlchemy docs themselves though.